# Are the Russian “рыжий” and French “rouge” (red) related? / Как связаны русское «рыжий» и французское «rouge»?

Tags: этимология, other-languages

While I since had learned that linguistics works in much more mysterious ways than simply “if words sounds alike, or also mean similar things, they must be related”, for a long time I presumed that the Russian word *рыжий* (red, ginger (of hair)) was not only related, but a direct borrowing from the French word *rouge* (red, vermillion (colour); blush (of face)).

I think, many people can make this or similar connections, and it could be useful to tell a more complex story.

---

Несмотря на то, что я узнал, что лингвистика ходит [куда более таинственными путями](http://elementy.ru/lib/430720#3), нежели простое «если слова звучат похоже и даже имеют сходные значения, то они должны быть связаны друг с другом», долгое время я предполагал, что русское слово *рыжий* было не только связано, но являлось прямым заимствованием французского слова *rouge* (красный, румяный).

Я думаю, многие люди могут делать такое же или подобные предположения и более сложное описание этой связи может оказаться полезным.

Comment: This question is based on [our discussion](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/338/do-русый-and-русский-have-a-common-root/340#340) with Mr. Quassnoi some time ago.

Comment: Wonderful question, and thanks a lot for providing a link to the site! I have watched Zaliznyak's lectures in VK, it'll be interesting indeed to read those articles too =)

Comment: I had been saying "да ну в африку / иди в африку" for all my childhood.(90-th) I was although saying "чёрт" on all mishaps, until onсe a nun scared me. What I mean is that the answer depends solely on child's interests and surroundings.

Answer (score 19):

*Short answer.* Yes, they are related.

*Long answer.* These words both are descending from the same PIE root  `reudh`, which stood for indicating something related to red. I use the phrase *something related to red*, since no one knows for sure (and, alas, no one most probably will know in future) whether this root in its first meaning indicated colour and then some additional meanings (blood, red-coloured fruits or berries etc.)  had been derived; or vice versa.

Actually, as far as I know, red is one of the few colours (if not the only one) for which we have solid evidence of common PIE origin. English words `red`, `rust`, `rusty`, Russian words `руда` (in some dialects of Old Russian this also meant "blood" by the way), `рыжий`, `рдеть`, `ржавый`, French word `rouge`, all of them are related.

*The longest answer I can provide.* French is a Romance language but its phonetic evolution was very intensive. If one would be asked to characterise this evolution in a single word, it wouldn't be a too bold oversimplification to say reduction. For example, the French word août (which [is pronounced just](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ao%C3%BBt) `u`) actually originally had been latin "augustus". Something similar had happened to the Latin word `rubeus` (red, reddish), which was transformed to modern `rouge`.

As for the Russian `рыжий`, it indeed is related to `рудый` which, in turn, is related to `руда`.

There is also one thing we always should remember almost each time when we are saying that two words in different languages are related in deep historical context: those relations are not always straightforward. It's not always that simple that there existed some word in some mother language and that word had precisely that meaning and had been derived from exactly that word.

For example, the above mentioned Latin word `rubeus` claimed to have had originated [from](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rubus) `rubus` (blackberry). And `rubus` is related to `wr̥dʰo` (some plant with red flowers, presumably sweetbrier or rose, or part of this plant). Oh, by the way, almost forgot to mention that `rose` is also related to `рыжий`, but, once again, not directly. And `wr̥dʰo` is, once again, related to the first PIE root I've mentioned.

Comment: A great one, +1.

Comment: Did you mean "rubeus" rather than "rebus"?

Comment: This is incorrect. First, the PIE word from which both "red", "rubeus" and "рыжий" are derived was "e̯roudhros" "red" (as words with initial r- were prohibited). You still can see the vestige of the initial laryngeal in "erythrocyte". Second, the root rubus is most likely related to the root "u̯era̯d-" "sprout", from which the words "root", "wart", "вред" originate.

Comment: @Quassnoi, yep, this was typo, fixed it.

Comment: @Anixx, can not see a contradiction between what I've said and what are you claiming. First, root does not mean word, it means корень, корневая основа. Second, root `rubus` and its "botanic" relations are also mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @shabunc You claimed that the PIE root for briar and the PIE root for red are related. They are not. e̯roudhros is not related to u̯era̯ds.

Comment: @Anixx: even if you don't subscribe to laryngeal theory, could you please stick to op's transcription rules while commenting (or at least mention the differences)? From your comment one could infer that *e̯roudhros (or *h₁roudʰros in op's transcription) is not related to *reudʰ- which is apparently wrong. Though *reudʰ- is hardly related to *wr̥dʰo- indeed.

Comment: @Quassnoi there was no such root *reudʰ-, simply because words(and roots) with initial r- were not possible. And also there of course could not be a root "wr̥dʰo" (with final vowel). My dictionary gives a form "u̯era̯ghos" for briar (notice the difference in the consonant), although the reliability of this stem is suspicious.

Comment: @Anixx: prosthetic laryngeals are usually omitted in the root lists.

Comment: @Quassnoi only if in very old lists, which do not account for laryngeal theory, such as Pokorny. Ommitting them is completely incorrect because this may lead to a confusion of different roots, a situation similar to what we see in this answer.

Comment: @Anixx: The American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots (2000) lists it as "REUDH-".

Comment: @Quassnoi oh this is a very inprecise dictionary, and it does not account for laryngeals at all. I think it is roughly based on Pokorny, a very outdated reconstruction. It has no value for the PIE studies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7381/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-anixx)

Comment: When I studied French, 'août' was pronounced [ut]. Are they going to pronounce the rest of their words with just one sound and to replace speech with gestures and mimics?

Comment: @КуЪ, you've studied right, it's just that de-facto in colloquial speech it is often pronounced just [u] )

Comment: @КуЪ and shabunc, I just saw it somewhere the other day on EL&U: the dictionary said something to the effect of [u] being some regional dialect.

Answer (score 4):

In Polish and Bulgarian there existed, though now obsolete, words *rydzy* and *рижд*. The latter is still used in modern Bulgarian to denote reddish-yellow color of animals (dogs and horses).

If we look at the yotation table, say, here:

- [Изменение согласных в сочетании с j в праславянском языке](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%81_j_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)

we will see that *ж* in an East Slavic version of the word, *dz* in a West Slavic one and *жд* in a South Slavic one is a sign that the word originated in Proto-Slavic and had been a subject to yotation.

This would give us the proto-Slavic word **rydjь*.

The borrowing, thus, cound not happen later than VII century if at all (after that time the Slavic families were separated too much).

By that time French rouge had not acquired its modern reading yet.

So that's impossible that *рыжий* is borrowed from *rouge*.

Comment: Related doesn't mean one derives from the other. That's similarly misled as the argument that man derives from ape, whereas science just claims a common ancestor.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: see the original discussion here: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/338. I've just copied and pasted it as an answer by op's request.

Comment: alright then. I also looked at the other one before you linked it. Thanks.